# adding items to listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I'm using vb.net forms

I'm trying to add items to a listbox one by one from many comboboxes and textboxes

the problem is when i add the second item to the listbox it replace the first one

i want the listbox to keep the first item and add a new one

here is my code

```
    Private Sub Button39_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button39.Click


    ListBox1.Items.Add(ComboBox1.Text.ToString() &
    " " & ComboBox2.Text.ToString() & "  " & textbox1.Text.ToString())
```

Comment: yes its working .. I mean when i add another item .. it replacing the first .. i want it to add the second below the first not replace the first

Comment: Is this your complete code? Are you sure you do not have a "ListBox1.Items.Clear" somewhere?

Comment: No there is not .. Must i add a loop to keep insert items to the listbox?

Comment: the listbox is at another form .. and i have a back button there that return me to the original form contains (me.close) .. is this the problem?

Comment: So maybe you have a new instance of ListBox1 and you recreate your form. So your instance gets lost.

Comment: You need to give us the complete code to help you out

Answer (score -1):

try with this changes

```
Private Sub Button39_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button39.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Add(ComboBox1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() & " " & ComboBox2.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() & "  " & textbox1.Text.ToString())
```